# React js - toggling a component when in a certain route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering how to toggle or hide a component when in a certain route. In my case I want to hide the header component when in the /dashboard route so I can replace it with a new one for the user to see. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With react-router you can call useLocation() to see your current url. Therefore you could do something like this:

```
function MainHeader () {
    return (
        <div>
             main header
        </div>
    )
}

function StaffHeader () {
    return (
        <div>
            Staff header
        </div>
     )
  }

function Header() {
    const [staffHeader, seStaffHeader] = useState(false)
    const location = useLocation()
    
    useEffect(()=> {
           setStaffHeader(location.pathname === "/dashboard")
    },[location])
    
    return (
        <div>
            {staffHeader ? <StaffHeader/> : <MainHeader/>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Above you have the two headers - MainHeader and StaffHeader.
And we call Header in the app. Every time the location changes the useEffect will check if location is equal to "./dashboard" and update the state of our staffHeader variable. Our Header component has a ternary operator the returns either MainHeader or StaffHeader according to  the state of staffHeader variable.

Link to react-router below:
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location

This solution above should do the trick. However, it's worse mentioning that you can get much more scalable solutions with Route authentication components that control user permissions. The link below will give a good and simple  starting point for this matter.
https://medium.com/@thanhbinh.tran93/private-route-public-route-and-restricted-route-with-react-router-d50b27c15f5e

Comment: It would be more clean and idiomatic to have a `Header` component that renders the specific headers into specific routes inside a switch and skip the local component state.

Comment: Yes! In deed it would be better. I will edit the answer adding a follow-up observation linking to a good post online for this matter for users who came across this question.